# Can I run CyanogenMod without mobile service?

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod, htc-droid-incredible

I am wondering if I can run CyanogenMod on a phone without service? I have an HTC Incredible and am thinking of upgrading to a new phone and wonder if I can give my old phone to my daughter to use like an iTouch works where you only have internet access via a wireless connection and cannot make cell phone calls but can use applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, even plain Android will do this.  I've heard of some unlicensed phones that didn't properly finish setup unless you had a SIM card but it shouldn't be an issue with CM.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have an Incredible - moved on to a Nexus! - and I noticed a ROM in the XDA forums that was for Wifi only, ie, device without a data plan.

You can [search here for it](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=638).

There is also a Wifi only mod that [can be found here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=969371).

Link to [Wifi Only Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1217038).